# Prevent Quantity Decrease on shipment generate

Tags: inventory, shipment, qty

I want to prevent the decrease product QTY after the shipment generation. Actually my client is using NetSuite and he want to update the QTY from there.

They are managing all orders from the NetSuite. So, is there any way to prevent QTY update after shipment generation.

Please let me know if you guys have any idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If NetSuite is the source of truth for Inventory, then you need to disable the Magento MSI reservation system. You may check the following opensource module for that https://github.com/AmpersandHQ/magento2-disable-stock-reservation

The above module will block the MSI reservation feature. When you place an order, Magento immediately decreases quantity to avoid overselling and when you create the shipment, Magento never decreases qty.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid decreases quantity  after order place, invoice and shipment all? In short, Inventory updated from Netsuite only.

Comment: How do you avoid overselling then if you disable the decreasing qty after the order is placed? Yes, possible. Install above module and block the decreasing code after placing order.

Comment: It works as expected. I have modified as per my requirement. Thanks!!!